# Laplace and KVL

Tags: voltage, capacitor, resistors, laplace-transform, kirchhoffs-laws

I was preparing for my exam by solving questions and there is this one question I was stuck on but when I saw its solution provided by book, I think KVL applied is not right or I am not able to understand it properly. Can some please help.

Books says -
(Xc + 6K + 4K)I(s) = - 160/9s

But I think it should be
(Xc + 6K + 4K) I(s) = 160/9s

[image: Solution in book]
please help.

Here is the question.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the direction you choose for the current. Book's answer is using \$I_c\$, that is, counter-clockwise direction, so the voltage across the source will be seen like a voltage drop. You are trying to use \$i_r\$, which is clockwise direction, so the source produces a voltage rise, opposite to the drop over the impedances. That is why the book's answer has the negative sign on the \$160/9s\$ term.

In your case, you will obviously arrive to \$i_r=\frac{16}{9}e^{-100t/3}\$, and when you calculate \$V_c(t)\$, you will have to use this equation:
$$
V_c(t)=V_{C10}-\frac{1}{c}\int_0^t{i_r(t)dt} 
$$
with the minus sign, because the voltage source and the impedance have opposite sign for the current you chose.

If you replace the value for \$i_r\$, you will get the same result as the book.

Comment: Thank you for help mate